# How to know touch duration in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

Is there any native cocos2d method to calculate touch duration or to detect long touch or small drag not using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of registering the time between a ccTouchBegan and ccTouchEnded event.

A UITouch object has this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval timestamp;
```

So simply store the value of the first time interval in some ivar when you get a ccTouchBegan event, and make the difference with the time that you get in ccTouchEnded.